# Builded electron application load node module on runtime

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I have a problem with an app based on electron. When I build my electron app with **electron-builder** it produces a appname.exe file which has probably the html/js/css sources in the exe file or another one in the produced directory. When I try to require a node_module from the developer console in the builded app, the module is not getting found :(.

The app is looking in a file called **electron.asar** liked it seems for the module. I don't really understand this because over modules are getting found, otherwise, the app would not be able to start anyhow.

Maybe one of you guy's have already faced that problem?

Comment: Mhhhh... I guess the module need to be listed in the **dependencies** section in the package.json like it seems :/.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the module needs to be listed in the dependencies section in the package.json to be found in the built electron app.